# Taking input on remote vm

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, shell-scripting, unix-shell

below is my use case , I have to take a input from a user for a specific command which need to run on a remote machine.But my problem is I am not able to access that machine directly so what I am doing

Ssh to othere server  and from their I am doing ssh to that server. But at that server we are not able to take any inout from user.

Below is a sample script:-

```
ssh user@machine1 /bin/bash <<\EOF1

ssh user@machine2 /bin/bash <<\EOF2

pwd
echo " Enter input  :"

read -r input

curl -XPOST -k -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{ "LOGIN_URL": "https://xyz/login","LOGIN_USER": "user11@gmail.com", "LOGIN_PASSWORD": "xyz", "CID": "'"$input"'" }' 'https://abc/gettoken' > sample

scp sample.txt root@user1:/root
```

It does not ask for user input and dirctly jump to scp command. Also is this a correct way to pass a variable in a curl command

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your shell variable in a JSON document in a curl command in a here document is not easy to work with. Super annoying to get quoting correct. Especially when this needs to be done to multiple hosts.

Consider writing short shell scripts. A wrapper script on localhost, that prompts the user, possibly with [stty -echo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980713/4735500) to hide sensitive values. The wrapper script then sftp's additional scripts and maybe JSON files to the remote servers, and runs them. Consider the use of JSON processors like `jq` to edit CID, rather than rely on shell variable expansion.

Or, some automation tools can help with running commands on remote hosts. For example, an Ansible play could make use of `vars_prompt` keyword for the password prompt,  `uri` module to do the POST, and save the response.